# Running a docker container in a docker network which is already created by a docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

For implementing integration tests for a project that I'm working on, there's a requirement to run integration tests by spinning up services as docker containers. So there are 2 services that stay in a fixed state through out the tests and those services are added into a docker-compose file. I am starting those services at the beginning of the tests. After that for a group of tests, I need to start another service using docker run command and add that service into the same network that is created when I start the previous 2 services as docker-compose. Is that possible ?

I tried the following steps to ensure that adding a docker container to a network created by docker-compose is possible or not.

1. Sample docker-compose file.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  backend_service_1:
    image: solsson/http-echo
    networks:
      - envoymesh
    environment:
      - PORT=8000 

networks:
  envoymesh:
    name: envoymesh
    driver: bridge
```

2. Run another docker container and try to add to the same network.

```sh
docker run solsson/http-echo -e PORT=9000 --network=envoymesh --driver=bridge
```

3. Run `docker network inspect envoymesh` to see the containers in the network. But I'm seeing only the container from the docker-compose.

```sh
 "Containers": {
            "bd3c1b20be141cc66144f24a7e7adeaaa894e694004139f88f2b9563c729e8e1": {
                "Name": "docker-network_backend_service_1_1",
                "EndpointID": "d43f97ef5f0948ed2f6c7e4045164439ebf2596176868efcf6640927c1bc376e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Is it possible to achieve my requirement ?? Thanks in advance.

**PS: docker network connect envoymesh [container id] works.**

---

**Solution**

It was a issue with the way that I was using the docker run command. It should be used like follows with image name at the end.

```sh
docker run -e PORT=8000 --network envoymesh solsson/http-echo
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the `docker run` command doesn't work but have you tried this:

```
docker network connect envoymesh container-name
```

**Command format:**

```
docker network connect [OPTIONS] NETWORK CONTAINER
```

**Description:**

*Connects a container to a network. You can connect a container by name or by ID. Once connected, the container can communicate with other containers in the same network.*

Source: [network connect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)

Comment: yeah it worked but i would like to have it with run commands since I'm calling these commands from source code and much cleaner to do it with run in a single command. Thanks

Comment: You can try --network='<network-name>|<network-id>' or --network='container:<name|id>' The second tag allows new container to reuse another container's network stack.

Comment: I tried `--network='<network-name>|<network-id>' ` and that's what mentioned in the question. Can't achieve my requirement with the container's network stack.

Comment: Have you tried this `--network='container:<name|id>' `

Comment: It may seem to work here since there are only 2 containers. But in my case, adding to a container's network stack won't work.

Comment: I guess the `--network='<network-name>'` tag only connects the container to a user created network (using docker network create command)

Comment: Yeah but in the compose I'm not using the default network. I have defined a custom network.

Comment: actually the network that you defined in the docker-compose.yml is a default network. To be honest, I'm not sure about this as well. You can create a new network and connect new containers with `--network=new-network` to test my hypothesis.

Comment: Another thing that I suspect is incorrect ports. You should be careful about `CONTAINER_PORT` and `HOST_PORT`. If you're pointing to a `HOST_PORT`, you have to create a new overlay network

Comment: I just tried by creating a new network and use that in docker run. Didn't work. When inspecting it shows no containers in that test network.

Comment: Have you tried this `--network container:<name|id>`, which allows new container to connect to a previously defined network. Do you see any error? What exactly the command that you used?

Comment: It won't help me in my case. And what I'm trying should be possible. https://linuxhint.com/docker_compose_bridge_networking/

Comment: I found the issue.It was an issue with the way that I was using the docker run. Container name should be at the end. See the edited solution in the question. Thanks for the help.